# Como configurar virtualhost para o xampp no Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, xampp

Alguém pode ensinar como configurar um virtualhost para o xampp no ubuntu?
Eu já tentei esse tutorial https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/302/how-to-setup-a-virtual-host-locally-with-xampp-in-ubuntu 
porém ao final não consegui o resultado esperado, que seria algo como digitar no navegador: http://myaplication e o navegador já redirecionar direto para minha aplicação e não ter que utilizar o tradicional http://localhost/myaplication

Answer (score 2):

Opa tudo bem ?

Primeiro é necessário descomentar dentro do arquivo /opt/lampp/etc/http.conf, a seguinte linha:

### #Virtual Host

### Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

---

Após isso edite o arquivo: /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost myaplication:80>
   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/pasta-do-projeto"
   ServerName myaplication
   <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/pasta-do-projeto">
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Por fim edite o arquivo e adicone o mesmo nome do virtualhost criado: /etc/hosts 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Reinicie o apache e tente acessar http://myaplication

Comment: Vlw @Viktor Hugo, era exatamente o que eu procurava. Mto Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Sequer um localhost eficiente e tenha todos os mesmo recursos que o xampp utilize o LAMP... O LAMP tem tudo que o XAMPP tem e a instalação é super facil, no ubuntu vc instala com o comando:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

mais detalhes aqui: http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/instale-lamp-no-linux-e-tenha-um-servidor-web-em-seu-pc/